# Fetching the param value form the url

Tags: jasperserver

From a web application, a url is called to the `jasper` server; the url has the `user_id` as one of the parameter. As soon as the `Jasper` server is logged in, I need to fetch the value of the user id to filter one another input parameter of the report.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your report has an input control with a name of user_id then it should get set with the value from the URL. If you want to use this param in another input control (e.g. a single select query control) then $P{user_id} will work.